# How does the while loop in this code work?

Tags: swift

I am trying to complete a [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/sum-of-two-integers/) on LeetCode and I have found this solution in Swift but I am really not sure what happens in this while loop of the code :

```
func getSum(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    var a = a
    var b = b

    while b != 0 {
        (a, b) = (a ^ b, (a & b) << 1)
    }
    return a
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-add-two-integer-numbers-without-plus-arithmetic-operator-java-example.html

Answer (score 2):

`(a, b) = (a ^ b, (a & b) << 1)` is doing a tuple assignment. It can be broken down into:

```
let oldA = a
let oldB = b
a = oldA ^ oldB
b = (oldA & oldB) << 1
```

`^` is the bit-wist exclusive-or (XOR) operator in Swift (and most C-like languages)
`&` is the bit-wise and (AND) operator in Swift (and most C-Like languages)

`<<` is the left bit shift operator. `x << 1` means "bit-shift x to the left by 1"

Comment: But note that splitting the operation into two lines will do something different since the second line will use the already updated `a` value, not the original one.

Comment: That's a really good point, I was wonder why it was done that way!

Answer (score 2):

As complement to [@Alexander Momchliov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38961384/4573247)—which explains the bit-wise operators used—note also that you needn't use mutable local scope variables and a `while` loop in the `getSum(...)` function, but can use the same bit-operator calculations in recursive calls to the function itself, e.g.

```
func getSum(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    if b == 0 { return a }
    return getSum(a ^ b, (a & b) << 1)
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, `if b == 0 { return a }` would be better understandable. I don't get why people  try to replace *all* early returns with `guard`. – Just my 2ct!

Comment: @MartinR after your prompt, I agree! I've been, like many, infected by the early-returns-by-`guard`-flu! Thanks :)